# Are PHP's $_GET and $_POST tied to the HTTP GET and POST methods, respectively?

Tags: php, http, post, get

I noticed that I can use [`$_GET`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php) inside a POST request, why is that possible?

HTML form:

```
<form method="POST" action="test.php?id=123">
  <input type="text" name="foo">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
var_dump($_GET, $_POST);
```

Output:

```
array (size=1)
  'id' => string '123' (length=3)

array (size=1)
  'foo' => string 'bar' (length=3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In contrary to what is suggested by their names, `$_GET` and `$_POST` are not tied to the [GET](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.3) and [POST](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.5) methods of the HTTP specification.

The query string (which is represented as an associative array in PHP's `$_GET` variable) can be part of any URL, wether you are doing a GET, POST, [PUT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-9.6) or any other method on that URL. Although query strings are most commonly used with GET methods, they are certainly not limited to them. So, when POSTing a form to a URL that contains a query string (as per the example), the keys and values of the query string will be available in the `$_GET` variable.

`$_QUERY_STRING` would probably have been a better name for this variable.

It works slightly different the other way around. Although the POST method is not the only one that can contain a body (for instance, a PUT request can as well), some testing reveals that `$_POST` only contains data in case of a POST request - it is empty in all other cases.

PHP does not have a `$_PUT` variable to use with PUT request, probably [because browsers only support GET and POST requests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779/are-the-put-delete-head-etc-methods-available-in-most-web-browsers) for form submission. Instead, you can use `file_get_contents("php://input")` to read from the incoming stream to PHP, and then use `str_parse()` to load the keys and values as an associative array:

```
parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"), $data);
```

Comment: Why did you answer your own question like this?

Comment: @OptimusCrime because I already knew the answer, and I wanted to share it with other people ;) [See Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: I found a number of questions about GET vs POST and about $_GET vs $_POST, but none of them covered this specific aspect. If you find one that does, let me know.

Comment: @OptimusCrime - answering your own question is fine. That's why the "ask question" page has a checkbox that opens an answer form to be posted at the same time as the question.